# Compiler functions and executables

Tags: c, compiler-construction, reverse-engineering

> Despite their seemingly disparate approaches to the development
>   environment, both UNIX and Windows do share a common architectural
>   back-end when it comes to compilers (and many many other things, as we
>   will find out in the coming pages). Executable generation is
>   essentially handled end-to-end on both systems by one program: the
>   compiler. Both systems have a single front-end executable that acts as
>   glue for essentially all 5 steps mentioned above.

on: http://www.savs.hcc.edu.tw/~chuavv/articles/RevEng/ch02.html#the_compiler

What does this mean? That the compiler on one machine compiles the program (preprocessing -> parsing -> translation -> assembly -> linking) and on the other machine, the compiler also performs the same task but in reverse? Not sure exactly what is meant by "Executable generation is essentially handled end-to-end on both systems ... executable that acts as glue for essentially all 5 steps."

Comment: I'm not sure where doing something in reverse is coming from. Compiling programs on Windows or on Unix work *basically* the same way.

Comment: seems pretty straightforward: "Executable generation is essentially handled end-to-end on both systems by one program"

Comment: There aren't many computer systems that don't 'share a common architectural back-end when it comes to compilers'. Rather a pretentious and pompus statement frankly.

Comment: @EJP: How the hell is that "pretentious" or "pompus[sic]"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically English reading comprehension, not programming.

> Executable generation is essentially handled end-to-end on both systems.

This means that from the beginning to the end, from the plaintext source to the final executable, one program, the compiler does all the work.

> executable that acts as glue for essentially all 5 steps.

Be it either GCC or MSVC, there's a driver, a kind of 'manager' executable that invokes the underlying preprocessor, parser, assembler and linker (these are CPP, cc1, as and ld in the case of GCC) executables. It's just an umbrella, a wrapper for its sub-programs.

I would, however, disagree with Win and Unix sharing a fundamental architecture. What they have in common is only the very basic stuff that can't really be done differently. E. g., they both have a kernel, they are capable of running on a Neumann-architecture computer, etc. Just as if the author said that car engines and hand mills share a common architecture merely because both are mechanical devices.

Answer (score 2):

It means that on both windows and linux you usually only use one program to compile your code into an executable. You don't have to run a separate program to do preprocessing and another for translation and another for linking. That one executable performs the whole process "end to end."